# Rearrange columns of a data frame and calculate mean

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large data frame of the following structure

```
input <- data.frame(c(1,2,3,4), c(5,6,7,8))
```

always two values are replicates (1 and 2, 3 and 4, 5 and 6, 7 and 8) and I want to calculate the mean for each pair and generate the following new data fame as an output

```
output <- data.frame(c(mean(c(1,2)), mean(c(3,4))),
                     c(mean(c(5,6)), mean(c(7,8))))
```

Thanks.

Comment: `library(dplyr); input %>% group_by(g = rep(seq(n() / 2), each = 2)) %>% summarise_all(mean) %>% select(-g)`

Comment: @Stella When you ask a question, someone answers; and if it works, you should accept it.

Comment: Hey, sorry. Thanks you very much for all answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
odd <- seq.int(1L, nrow(input), 2L)  ## odd row index
output <- (input[odd, ] + input[-odd, ]) / 2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
aggregate(x = input, by = list(replic, pair), FUN = "mean")
#   Group.1 Group.2   a   b
# 1    rep1       1 1.5 5.5
# 2    rep2       2 3.5 7.5
```

data:

```
input <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4), b = c(5,6,7,8))
replic <- rep(c('rep1', 'rep2'), each=2)
pair <- rep(c(1,2), each = 2)
```

Comment: Could also do something like `aggregate(. ~ id, transform(input, id = rep(1:(nrow(input)/2), each = 2)), mean)`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rowsum`

```
rowsum(input, group = rep(1:2, each = 2))/2
#    a   b
#1 1.5 5.5
#2 3.5 7.5
```

For a general case,

```
rowsum(input, group = (seq_len(nrow(input))-1)%/%2 + 1)/2
```

Or as suggested by @李哲源ZheyuanLi

```
rowsum(input, gl(nrow(input) / 2, 2))/2
```